# Populate JQ Grid from JSON String JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

i want to populate JQGrid table from JSON String, but after a number of tries i still get blank table.

[image]

that is the table

[image]

that is the JSON string message[image]

and this is my javascript code. it's there any problem with my code? i have tried manual string JSON and it worked, but getting JSON from url fails every time.

Comment: Do you have any error in the console when try to get the data from the url? The settings are correct except that the sortname should be set as `sortname: 'ID'` instead of `sortname: 'id'`

Answer (score 0):

In the colModel use like following

`colModel: [ {name:'rows.0.ID', index:'rows.0.ID', width:300},`

`{name:'rows.0.name', index:'rows.0.name', width:300},`

`{name:'rows.0.desc', index:'rows.0.desc', width:300} ]`